# Show Prolog "write" output in Console Java

Tags: java, console, prolog

I'm using JPL Libraries to link a Prolog program with Java interface. 
I have a (working) JTextArea where I redirect everything that appears in Console, but I can't see the prolog "write" instruction. 
I used this method for queries:

```
Query q2 = new Query(t2);
System.out.println("Query " + t2 + " is " + (q2.hasSolution()));
```

but when the query is false, the text in "write" parts of Prolog for example:

```
write('Sorry, you can''t go from the '), write(CurPlace), write(' to the '),    write(Place), nl,
```

doesn't appear in JTextArea.

I tried also with `System.out.println("first solution of " + q2 + ": X = " + q2.oneSolution().get("X"));` but it doesn't work.

What happen in JTextArea is this:
Query goto(garage).
 is false
but I expected also the "write" warnings contained in .pl file. For example:

```
write('Sorry, you don''t have the keys')
```

Comment: Maybe you need to finish the message with a newline: just call  `nl` after calling `write`.

Comment: It doesn't work, thank you anyway

Comment: You can also try a call to `flush_output` instead. If this fails the problem most probably is in the JPL libraries.